# How to convert ccsprite to ccimage cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

```
// new image from png file
CCImage* img = new CCImage();
img->initWithImageFile( "2.png");

// new texture from image
CCTexture2D* tex = new CCTexture2D();
tex->initWithImage( img );

// create sprite 

m_pSpr = CCSprite::create();
m_pSpr->setPosition( ccp( 100, 100 ) );
this->addChild( m_pSpr );

m_pSpr->setTexture( tex );

    this is only ccimage to ccsprite  but i want to get sprite to ccimage.
    how to do 

 m_pSpr = CCSprite::create("2.png");
    m_pSpr->setPosition( ccp( 100, 100 ) );
    this->addChild( m_pSpr );

       CCImage* img = new CCImage();
        img->initWithImageFile( "m_pSpr getname");
```

Comment: What you try give in detail

Comment: void hellworld:: istab(sprite*sp)
{Image* imgPtr = new cocos2d::Image();
 imgPtr->initWithImageFile( "sp_sprite_name" );////how to set sp sprite path 
 const int width = imgPtr ->getWidth();
    const int height = imgPtr ->getHeight();}

Comment: @himanshukalal can you post your solution please ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
    // sprite is the CCSprite object.
    CCRenderTexture* r = CCRenderTexture::create(sprite->getTexture()->getPixelsWide(), sprite->getTexture()->getPixelsHigh());

    r->beginWithClear(1, 1, 1, 0);
    sprite->visit();
    r->end();

    CCImage *testImage = r->newCCImage();
```

Answer (score 2):

i m using above code , this give me black background image.
How to convert CCsprite to UIImage in cocos2dx version 3.2